# Automatic creation of mutisite blog outside of the admin

Tags: multisite

i working on a system that  in which i want user to be able to create their own page on login using the multisite feature in wordpress how do i get these done outside the admin. It seems like all the files in wordpress are all interwoven. i dont understand how all those function and class can be  included into my project

Answer (score 1):

You could use this WordPress function within your form code:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpmu_create_blog
With this and a custom template you can allow any user to create a blog for himself (For some sample code you could see how wordpress itself does it on `wp-signup.php` on WordPress root dir)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! got it now. To add to that, call the general wordpress class using include(your word press root/wp-load.php) then any other function